# Definición de Variables en C++

Tags: c++

Estoy en proceso de aprendizaje de estos lenguajes y tengo la duda de cuales son las diferencias si yo defino una variable y le asigno un parametro a si primero creo la variable y despues la defino por ejemplo

```
int variable = 10;
```

a

```
int variable;
variable = 10;
```

tomando esto como ejemplo mis dudas.

1. Se usa el mismo espacio de memoria en el archivo?
2. Que pasa si el valor que le quiero asignar a la variable es una variable que no tiene ningun valor.
3. Es mejor inicializar la variable con un valor y despues asignar el valor que quiero?
4. Si uso `unsigned o signed` va ocupar menos memoria y va hacer mas rapido el procesamiento?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La respuesta, en C++, con su orientación a objetos y constructores, es más amplia de lo que parece. Afortunadamente, la pregunta se limita a `int`, que es un *tipo básico*, sin constructor, y facilita bastante la tarea.

C/C++ distinguen entre *almaceniento automático* y *almacenamiento estático* (en realidad hay más, pero nos limitareamos a la pregunta).

Las variables con *almacenamiento estático* tienen la misma duración que el programa en el que se usan. Son aquellas que se declaran **fuera** de cualquier función, o bien, **dentro** del cuerpo de la función, utilizando la palabra clave `static`:

```
int a; // Fuera de ninguna función. Estática.

int myfunc( ) {
  static int b; // Dentro del cuerpo, con 'static'. Estática.
  ...
}
```

Las variables con *almacenamiento automático* **solo se pueden declarar dentro del cuerpo de una función**, y solo *existen* mientras estamos ejecutando el código **dentro de dicha función**. **No** se preceden de ninguna palabra clave:

```
int myfunc( ) {
  int b; // Dentro del cuerpo, sin 'static'. Automática.
  ...
}
```

#### 1. Se usa el mismo espacio de memoria en el archivo?

Si, en ambos casos. Las estáticas se inicializan a **0** si no lo haces tú con algún valor, y las automáticas **no** ocupan ningún espacio.

#### 2. Que pasa si el valor que le quiero asignar a la variable es una variable que no tiene ningun valor.

Si el compilador es decente y estamos hablando de variables automáticas, el compilador *emite* un **aviso**. Es perfectamente legal, y puede ser usado para varias cosas (datos aleatorios). Y la asignación se realiza correctamente, con lo que tendrías **2** variables con contenido *indeterminado*.

Si estamos hablando de variables estáticas, **siempre se inicializan**, por ti con el valor que quieras, o bien por el copilador, que les asigna **0**.

#### 3. Es mejor inicializar la variable con un valor y despues asignar el valor que quiero?

Puede que el compilador emita código *mas eficiente* en un caso o en otro (para tipos básicos). Desde nuestro punto de vista, es exactamente igual; cuestión de gustos. Al final, va a terminar con el valor que tu le indiques.

#### 4. Si uso unsigned o signed va ocupar menos memoria y va hacer mas rapido el procesamiento?

Ambos son *modificadores*, **no** tipos. Si no indicas otro tipo, se utiliza `int` como tipo; es decir `signed a;` **es igual a** `signed int a;`. Ambos pueden utilizarse con los tipos enteros básicos: `char`, `short`, `int`, `long` y, últimamente, `long long`. **no** se pueden utilizar con tipos en coma flotante.

En última instancia, lo que influye en la *velocidad* es el **tamaño** del tipo; en realidad es mas complejo, y depende del *tamaño de palabra del procesador* (a grandes rasgos). Mi consejo es que te centres primero en aprender el lenguaje, y dejes *la velocidad* y *otras optimizaciones* para más adelante.

Comment: Efectivamente la declaración de objetos en C++ daría para otro hilo adicional. Yo creo que lo mejor en este caso es centrarse en tipos nativos, que es lo que de momento le preocupa. Si extendemos a objetos entonces la respuesta podría ser casi interminable

Comment: Cierto. Lo indico solo *de pasada*; principalmente, dado que afirma *estar aprendiendo*, para que valla *pasito a pasito*, que es un camino largo ... y con curvas.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Se usa el mismo espacio de memoria en el archivo?

La memoria se reserva en el momento que declaras la variable. Asignaciones posteriores lo único que hacen es modificar el valor almacenado por dicha variable.

> 2. Que pasa si el valor que le quiero asignar a la variable es una variable que no tiene ningun valor.

En este caso la variable tendrá un valor indeterminado. Dicho valor es el que se encontrase en la memoria antes de reservar la misma para la variable (recuerda que la memoria es un recurso compartido).

> 3. Es mejor inicializar la variable con un valor y después asignar el valor que quiero?

Lo ideal es asignar un valor al declarar la variable. Hacer esto se conoce como inicialización.

Que las variables tengan un valor inicial conocido evita muchos errores tontos y difíciles de encontrar.

> 4. Si uso unsigned o signed va ocupar menos memoria y va hacer mas rapido el procesamiento?

El uso de variable con signo o sin signo no tiene repercusión en la velocidad de ejecución ni en el tamaño de la variable. Esto únicamente va a afectar al rango de valores que es capaz de manejar la variable.

Answer (score 1):

Contesto de memoria:

1 Al declarar la variable, reserva la memoria necesaria según el tipo, por lo que ocupa la misma memoria asignes un valor o no.

2 Al declarar una variable sin asignar nada, su valor es lo que contenga la memoria reservada, puede que un dato "aleatorio" o se inicialize a 0, según el compilador. Asi que si asignas el valor de una variable no asignada, puede resultar 0 o un valor "aleatorio".

3 Es básicamente indiferente, te ahorras una línea asignando directamente...

4 No ocupa menos memoria, ocupa la misma, pero el bit mas significativo se usara para indicar el signo en caso de signed.